# Recognize gesture that's not in a certain subview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to use UIGestureRecognizers to distinguish between two kinds of gestures: those occurring in a mini-UIView and those occurring anywhere else in the view.

I thought I could accomplish this with two GestureRecognizers using requireGestureRecognizerToFail. However, the parent view's GestureRecognizer never fires. Why is this?

Here is a demonstrative test case:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    UIView *miniView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,20,20)] autorelease];
    miniView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:miniView];

    // triggered when you tap the miniView
    UITapGestureRecognizer *miniTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(miniTap:)] autorelease];
    [miniView addGestureRecognizer:miniTap];

    // expected: triggered when you tap anywhere outside the mini-view
    // actual: never triggered!
    UITapGestureRecognizer *nonMiniTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(nonMiniTap:)] autorelease];
    [nonMiniTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:miniTap];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:nonMiniTap];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void)miniTap:(id)sender { NSLog(@"miniTap"); }

-(void)nonMiniTap:(id)sender { NSLog(@"nonMiniTap"); }
```

Why does requireGestureRecognizerToFail: prevent nonMiniTap from ever being triggered? Can I make it behave in the expected way?

Comment: What's the state of userInteractionEnabled in all of the objects in the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation for [`requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it is stated clearly that the gesture's state isn't changed from `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible` until the other gesture transitions to `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`. But since the `miniTap` gesture doesn't move out of its default `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible` state as the touch isn't within its view, the `nonMiniTap` gesture isn't recognized. So your taps on the parent view are failing.

As such that dependency isn't required. You can take that line off and it should work as you want it to.